# AOSP Debug system_process with Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, service, android-source, platform

After successfull setup Android Studio to debug some default process like Calculator or com.android.server.telecom, I'm trying to debug the WifiService "process".

However, the WifiService class is execute in thread into "system_process" process.

Currently, to debug a process, I use Android Device Monitor to launch ddms, and in (on phone under lollipop) Settings > Developer options > Select debug app, and I select my process as well.

But the system_process doesn't appear. As when you select the process, Android kill it and are waiting for a new execution, I understand why it is not list (if you choose it the phone couldn't be run !).

So... How can I debug the processus ? Are there any other way ?

Even if there are just a way to debug a SystemService (ie : here the wifi who interest me), it could be gratefull to know that.

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

To debug this process, I use Eclipse (neon version) and that's work perfectly.

So for this configuration I use :

- AndroidStudio to have aosp setup;
- DDMS from monitor binary;
- Eclipse in remote debug config.

First I connect to my platform with adb command.
Second I select the process in Monitor windows.
Third I run the debug process and place breakpoint.

++

Comment: You could setup remote debug in Android Studio too: http://ronubo.blogspot.ru/2016/01/debugging-aosp-platform-code-with.html  , and  https://shuhaowu.com/blog/setting_up_intellij_with_aosp_development.html